# Adding arrays into an array, and associate it with a specific key

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

I have an array like so:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'player',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
```

I then have another array, such as:

```
[stateArray] => Array
    (
        [0] => OR
        [1] => WI
    )
```

Which I need to add to the original `$args` array to specifically get this result:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'player',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'compare' => 'AND',
           [0] => array(
               'key'     => 'state',
               'value'   => 'OR',
               'compare' => '=',
           ),
           [1] => array(
                'key'     => 'state',
                'value'   => 'WI',
                'compare' => '=',
                ),
    )
);
```

Trying this code:

```
$stateArray = $_POST['stateArray'];
$state_array_wrapper = array('meta_query' => array());
foreach ($stateArray as $state) {
    $single_state_array = array(
        'key'     => 'town_state',
        'value'   => $state,
        'compare' => '='
    );
    array_push($state_array_wrapper, $single_state_array);
}
$state_array_wrapper = array_values($state_array_wrapper);
array_push($args, $state_array_wrapper);
```

I get this result:

```
Array (
[post_type] => player
[posts_per_page] => -1
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [key] => town_state
                [value] => OR
                [compare] => =
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [key] => town_state
                [value] => WI
                [compare] => =
            )

    )

 )
```

Not sure why I don't see `'meta_query'` in the final array there at all, or how to just push those two `$single_state_array`s into meta_query even if I did see it showing up. How can this be done properly?

Comment: The example you show as "what I  need" is impossible. You can't have elements in an array that don't have key values. You inserted two arrays into an array, but neither one has a key. The answers below give them key values 0 and 1.

Comment: Sure @kainaw, you're correct. I update the question. I am not familiar with why, when writing code like this you don't have to write the [0] => parts but the chosen answer below worked for me, keys and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your $args the key for meta_query
then you need to push to that array

```
$args['meta_query'] = array('compare'=>'AND');

foreach ($stateArray as $state) {

    $single_state_array = array(
        'key'     => 'town_state',
        'value'   => $state,
        'compare' => '='
    );

    array_push($args['meta_query'], $single_state_array);
    /* short hand in php 7 */
    //$args['meta_query'][] = $single_state_array;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, worked like a charm! And thanks for the note on the php 7 shorthand!

Comment: That also works in php, hoping your using php 7,
php 5 requires arrays to be created as "array()", php 7 you can use "$arr = [];"
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

This appears straightforward. Please tell me if I am misreading it...

```
$args['meta_query'] = array('compare'=>'AND');
foreach($stateArray as $val)
  $args['meta_query'][] = array('key'=>'town_state', 'value'=>$val, 'compare'=>'=');
```

That's all.